# React Yelp API Call Using Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, get, axios, yelp

I've been banging my head trying to figure this out. I'm trying to call Yelp's API using axios, but I'm getting the following errors.

> OPTIONS https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search 403
>   Failed to load https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search: Response for
>   preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

I took care of the CORS issue by turning CORS off with a chrome extension. I've tested the API request successfully with Postman, so there isn't any issues with the Bearer token I'm using or the URL.

Below is the code I'm using to call the API.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';

const config = {
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer token'},
};

class Results extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            items: []
        };
    }


    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search', config)
        .then(response => console.log(response));
    }
```

Comment: How are you passing in your token in the request?

Comment: Right now I'm literally just pasting the API key in where 'token' is.